# Не появляеться картинка в емейле

Tags: node.js, ejs

В темплейте ejs для емейла картинка не появляется
В урле в inspect есть null
Помогите пофиксить

```
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
    style="width:100%;font-family:helvetica, 'helvetica neue', arial, verdana, sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;padding:0;Margin:0;">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
    <title></title>
    <!--[if (mso 16)]>
    <style type="text/css">
        a {text-decoration: none;}
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <style>
        @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

            p,
            ul li,
            ol li,
            a {
                font-size: 16px !important
            }

            h1 {
                font-size: 30px !important;
                text-align: center
            }

            h2 {
                font-size: 26px !important;
                text-align: center
            }

            h3 {
                font-size: 20px !important;
                text-align: center
            }

            h1 a {
                font-size: 30px !important
            }

            h2 a {
                font-size: 26px !important
            }

            h3 a {
                font-size: 20px !important
            }

            .es-header-body p,
            .es-header-body ul li,
            .es-header-body ol li,
            .es-header-body a {
                font-size: 16px
            }

            .es-footer-body p,
            .es-footer-body ul li,
            .es-footer-body ol li,
            .es-footer-body a {
                font-size: 16 px
            }

            .es-infoblock p,
            .es-infoblock ul li,
            .es-infoblock ol li,
            .es-infoblock a {
                font-size: 12px
            }

            *[class="gmail-fix"] {
                display: none !important
            }

            .es-m-txt-c,
            .es-m-txt-c h1,
            .es-m-txt-c h2,
            .es-m-txt-c h3 {
                text-align: center !important
            }

            .es-m-txt-r,
            .es-m-txt-r h1,
            .es-m-txt-r h2,
            .es-m-txt-r h3 {
                text-align: right !important
            }

            .es-m-txt-l,
            .es-m-txt-l h1,
            .es-m-txt-l h2,
            .es-m-txt-l h3 {
                text-align: left !important
            }

            .es-m-txt-r a img,
            .es-m-txt-c a img,
            .es-m-txt-l a img {
                display: inline !important
            }

            .es-button-border {
                width: 100% !important
            }

            .es-button {
                font-size: 20px !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                border-width: 10px 0px 10px 0px !important
            }

            .es-btn-fw {
                border-width: 10px 0px !important;
                text-align: center !important
            }

            .es-adaptive table,
            .es-btn-fw,
            .es-btn-fw-brdr,
            .es-left,
            .es-right {
                width: 100% !important
            }

            .es-content table,
            .es-header table,
            .es-footer table,
            .es-content,
            .es-footer,
            .es-header {
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 600px !important
            }

            .es-adapt-td {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100% !important
            }

            .adapt-img {
                width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important
            }

            .es-m-p0 {
                padding: 0px !important
            }

            .es-m-p0r {
                padding-right: 0px !important
            }

            .es-m-p0l {
                padding-left: 0px !important
            }

            .es-m-p0t {}

            .es-m-p0b {
                padding-bottom: 0 !important
            }

            .es-m-p20b {
                padding-bottom: 20px !important
            }

            .es-hidden {
                display: none !important
            }

            table.es-table-not-adapt,
            .esd-block-html table {
                width: auto !important
            }

            table.es-social {
                display: inline-block !important
            }

            table.es-social td {
                display: inline-block !important
            }

            .es-menu td a {
                font-size: 16px !important
            }
        }
    </style>
    <style>
        #outlook a {
            padding: 0;
        }

        .ExternalClass {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .ExternalClass,
        .ExternalClass p,
        .ExternalClass span,
        .ExternalClass font,
        .ExternalClass td,
        .ExternalClass div {
            line-height: 100%;
        }

        .es-button {
            mso-style-priority: 100 !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }

        a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
            color: inherit !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            font-size: inherit !important;
            font-family: inherit !important;
            font-weight: inherit !important;
            line-height: inherit !important;
        }

        @-ms-viewport {
            width: device-width;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body
    style="width:100%;font-family:helvetica, 'helvetica neue', arial, verdana, sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;padding:0;Margin:0;">
    <div class="es-wrapper-color" style="background-color:rgb(246, 246, 246);">
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
        <v:fill type="tile"
                color="#f6f6f6"

                src="">
        </v:fill>
    </v:background>
    <![endif]-->
        <table class="es-wrapper" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"
            style="box-sizing: border-box;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border: 1px solid #e9e9e9; border-radius: 3px;border-collapse: separate;border-spacing:0px;padding:0;Margin:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center top;">
            <tbody>
                <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <td valign="top" style="padding:20px;Margin:0;">
                        <table class="es-content" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"
                            style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%;">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                                    <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;">
                                        <table class="es-content-body"
                                            style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);"
                                            cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="570"
                                            align="center">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                                                    <td class="es-p20t es-p5b es-p15r es-p15l"
                                                        style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px;padding-top:20px;background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);"
                                                        bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left">
                                                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"
                                                            style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                                                                    <td class="es-m-p0r" width="540" valign="top"
                                                                        align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;">
                                                                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                                                                            width="100%"
                                                                            style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;">
                                                                                <tbody style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                                                                                    <td align="center"
                                                                                        style="padding:0;Margin:0;">
                                                                                        <img class="adapt-img" src="/public/logo.svg" alt="ggg">
                                                                                    <td>
                                                                            </tbody>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="es-content" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"
            style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%;">
            <tbody>
                <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;">
                        <table class="es-content-body" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="570"
                            align="center"
                            style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                                    <td class="es-p10t es-p10b es-p20r es-p20l" align="left"
                                        style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;">
                                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"
                                            style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                                                    <td width="530" valign="top" align="center"
                                                        style="padding:0;Margin:0;">
                                                        <table
                                                            style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:0px;border-radius:0px;"
                                                            cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                                                                    <td class="es-p5t es-p10b es-p15r es-p15l"
                                                                        align="center"
                                                                        style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px;">
                                                                        <p
                                                                            style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:20px;font-family:helvetica, 'helvetica neue', arial, verdana, sans-serif;line-height:150%;color:rgb(0, 0, 0);text-align:left;">
                                                                            <%- data.emailText.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>' )
                                                                                %>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                                                                    <td class="es-m-txt-c es-p20t es-p10b"
                                                                        align="center"
                                                                        style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:20px;">
                                                                        <span class="es-button-border"
                                                                            style="border-style:solid;border-color:rgb(44, 181, 67);background:rgb(0, 0, 145) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;border-width:0px;display:inline-block;border-radius:5px; width: 300px;height: 40px">
                                                                            <a href="<%= data.link %>" class="es-button"
                                                                                target="_blank"
                                                                                style="mso-style-priority:100 !important;text-decoration:none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:rgb(255, 255, 255);border-style:solid;border-color:rgb(0, 0, 145);border-width:10px 80px;display:inline-block;background:rgb(0, 0, 145) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;border-radius:5px;font-weight:bold;font-style:normal;line-height:120%;width:auto;text-align:center;">
                                                                                <%= data.buttonTitle || 'Click here!' %>
                                                                            </a> </span>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                                                                    <td class="es-p5t es-p10b es-p15r es-p15l"
                                                                        style="color:#717171;padding:0;Margin:0;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px;">
                                                                        <p
                                                                            style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:20px;font-family:helvetica, 'helvetica neue', arial, verdana, sans-serif;line-height:150%;color:rgb(0, 0, 0);text-align:left;">
                                                                        <p>
                                                                            If a browser page does not
                                                                            open after clicking the
                                                                            button above, please copy
                                                                            and paste the following link
                                                                            into a new browser tab:
                                                                        </p>
                                                                        <p>
                                                                            <%= data.link %>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="es-footer" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"
            style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%;background-color:transparent;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center top;">
            <tbody>
                <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;">
                        <table class="es-footer-body"
                            style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);"
                            cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="570" align="center">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                                    <td class="es-p15t es-p5b es-p20r es-p20l" align="left"
                                        style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:15px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;">
                                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"
                                            style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                                                    <td width="530" align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;">
                                                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"
                                                            style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                                                                    <td class="es-m-txt-c es-p10t es-p10b es-p5r es-p5l"
                                                                        align="center"
                                                                        style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">
                                                                        <p
                                                                            style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:14px;font-family:helvetica, 'helvetica neue', arial, verdana, sans-serif;line-height:150%;color:rgb(128, 128, 128);">
                                                                            <a style="color: gray; text-decoration: none;"
                                                                                href="<%= data.terms_of_service_link %>">Terms
                                                                                of Service</a>
                                                                            <span style="margin: 5px;">&#124;</span>
                                                                            <a style="color: gray; text-decoration: none;"
                                                                                href="<%= data.privacy_policy_link %>">Privacy
                                                                                Policy</a>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Как вы делаете? Что делаете? По приведенному отрывку HTML разметки сложно дать хоть какой либо ответ

Comment: @SwaD Дал полную страницу